# Process.Close() is not working and Process.CloseMainWindow() is throwing System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, .net, invalidoperationexception

I am trying to open an excel file by using the Process.Start() and then after some time I have to close the opened excel file. Here is the code for this.

```
        var process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            UseShellExecute = true,
            FileName = file
        };
        process.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(60000);
        process.CloseMainWindow();
```

I am able to open the file but at process.CloseMainWindow(), it throws an exception "No process is associated with this object". I have tried process.Close() but it didn't worked too(no exception was thrown). The process object shows System.InvalidOperationException. Please anyone help me in resolving this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Before closing process, check if `!process.HasExited`.

Comment: Same exception (No process is associated with this object) is thrown at process.HasExited.

Comment: add   `process.Close();` after `process.CloseMainWindow();` to Free resources associated with process. you can also try ` .kill()` function like here  `process.Kill();`

Comment: Tried that too but at process.CloseMainWindow() it gets exception

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want your code to continue after the user is done manipulating the file you want excel to open, I would suggest that you use `process.WaitForExit();`

You can then set a timeout on the wait method like this:

```
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    UseShellExecute = true,
    FileName = file
};
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit(60000);
```

If the timeout is reached the process will stop and out can then parse the output for errors by adding:

```
RedirectStandardError = true
RedirectStandardOutput = true
```

to your `StartInfo()` object

Comment: Tried this but it throws an InvalidOperationException at UseShellExecute. So, I set UseShellExecute to False and tried again. This time the exception is Win32Exception. The same code works fine in a sample project but fails in current project. Aslo, my process object shows System.InvalidOperationException for all properties in it.

Comment: @Shareef When you choose to use ProcessStartInfo() to start a file, Windows will try to start the default program associated with that files of that type. 
So if Excel is not installed or associated with the file you are trying to open, the operation will most likely not bahave as you would expect.